# Remove a flag from CFLAGS in FreeBSD makefile

Tags: makefile, freebsd, cflags, bsdmake, bmake

In a GNU makefile, it is possible to use filter-out to remove a flag from CFLAG like this :

```
CFLAGS:=$(filter-out -flag,$(CFLAGS))
```

However, I can't make it work with a FreeBSD makefile.

Is filter-out supported by FreeBSD ? Otherwise, what can I do to remove a specific flag from CFLAGS in a makefile ?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, there is *filter-out*-like feature in FreeBSD's Makefile but with different syntax:

> :Npattern
>         This is identical to `:M', but selects all words which do not match
>         pattern.

From [man make](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=make&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%2012.1-RELEASE%20and%20Ports&arch=default&format=html).

Usage example:

```
CFLAGS= -foo -bar -flag

all:
    @echo ${CFLAGS}
    @echo ${CFLAGS:N-flag}
```

The output:

```
$ make
-foo -bar -flag
-foo -bar
```